# Why does "L.insert(it--, i);" behave differently from "L.insert(it, i); it--;"?

Tags: c++, std

These are two pieces of code that I ran under the C++11 standard. I expected the post-decrement of the iterator to produce the same effect, but these two pieces of code produce completely different results. Where is my understanding off?

```cpp
list<int> L;

int main() {    
    L.push_back(0);
    L.push_front(1);
    auto it = L.begin();
    for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
        L.insert(it--, i);
    }
    for (auto num : L) {
        printf("%d ", num);
    }
    // 2 5 0 4 1 3
}
```

```cpp
list<int> L;

int main() {    
    L.push_back(0);
    L.push_front(1);
    auto it = L.begin();
    for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
        L.insert(it, i);
        it--;
    }
    for (auto num : L) {
        printf("%d ", num);
    }
    // 5 4 3 2 1 0
}
```

Comment: I think you should read about "Order of evaluation" in cppreference

Comment: the cases where post/pre increment are actually useful are rare compared to how often it is used. Here you could use [`std::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) to get the previous iterator. It would cause the same issue but less confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider *exactly* when the post-decrement happens.  In the second case, obviously the insert happens, modifying the list itself.  The iterator is still valid, pointing now at the second entry.  Then the decrement is computed, moving the iterator to the first entry.

In the first case, however, the post-decrement "makes a copy" of the iterator, performs the decrement, and returns the previous version.  That means that the new value of the iterator is computed *before* the insert happens, which is invalid since it already points at the first element.  Note that the insert still happens correctly, because the post-decrement returns the original and still-valid iterator.

This is not about post- vs. pre- decrement behavior.  It's about when the side-effect of the decrement actually happens.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order, specifically

> 3. When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline, and
>    whether or not explicit function call syntax is used), every value
>    computation and side effect associated with any argument expression,
>    or with the postfix expression designating the called function, is
>    sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the
>    body of the called function.

Answer (score 7):

```
L.insert(it, i);
it--;
```

This inserts a node before `it`, then moves `it` backwards to the inserted node.

```
L.insert(it--, i);
```

The order of operations is swapped: it moves the iterator backwards *before* `insert()` is called. There's no node to move back to so it causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour.

> The begin iterator is not decrementable and the behavior is undefined if --container.begin() is evaluated.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator

As such, anything could happen.